# Is Cloudera director 2.8.1 python sdk supports 3.4+?

Tags: python, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-director

Currently am using Cloudera director 2.8.1 to auto setup, install and configure CDH (5.16.2) cluster in AWS with python sdk using version 2.7

May I know if I can use python3 to bootstrap cluster with Cloudera director 2.8.1?

For the master branch (or latest version of Altus director) I could see it supports both 2.7 and 3.4+

https://github.com/cloudera/director-sdk/tree/master/python-client

But for 2.8.1 , I couldn't find python version requirement.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm on the Altus Director team at Cloudera.) We use Swagger 1.5 / OpenAPI 2.0 to generate the SDK / client code, so you might be able to generate Python 3 client code yourself using those tools. However, we do use a slightly modified Python generator class, so there's some chance that your own generated code will have warts not present in what's available at https://github.com/cloudera/director-sdk .

I'll file an internal ticket for us to try generating a Python 3 client. It makes sense to do so given the impending retirement of Python 2.

Comment: Thank you very much @bhavanki , This helps us a lot. I was trying to get an answer from Cloudera team and posted same question in Cloudera community (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-Cloudera-director-2-8-1-python-sdk-does-it-support-3-4/m-p/278368 )but couldn't get an answer , am happy that I could get you :)

Comment: As I've no knowledge on Swagger 1.5/ OpenAPI 2.0 ; is there a document or procedure that I can follow to generate code in Python 3? would it be possible for you to update this thread if Cloudera generates code in 3?

Comment: Do we have Python 3 client available now?

Answer (score 1):

If you download the [source code of 2.8.1](https://github.com/cloudera/director-sdk/releases/tag/cloudera-director-2.8.1) and check in the `python-client` directory, the `setup.py` contains

```
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
]
```

so no, it does not seem like the python client supports any python 3x versions

Comment: Thanks @Flying Teller